# Laptop doesn't boot after changing the HDD to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd

I have a laptop with two drives :

- small SSD (with windows)
- HDD (half linux, half data)
  I wanted to replace the HDD with a new SSD (samsung evo) with the same size. So I cloned everything to the new SSD but it didn't want to boot on it. **I have a black screen**

So I tried something else:

1. I deleted grub to boot directly in windows
2. I formatted the new SSD in ntfs
3. I replaced the old HDD by the new SSD (empty)

**Now I have a black screen again on boot, I cannot even access to the BIOS**

I checked everything :

the sata cable works fine, If I plug the old HDD it works fine

the SSD works fine, I tried it thanks to sata -> USB cable. I even tried to install a system on it and I could boot on it through the usb port.

If I just remove the disk (so there's only the small ssd with windows), it works and it boots on windows

So I was thinking maybe it was due to the alimentation but again I don't understand how it could be possible. Both are 5V and normally, a SSD should consume less power than HDD.

Does anyone know how I could fix this problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I thought I said hello but I didn't. So Hello everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem can occur if the new drive is specified at an different SATA level than the old one it should replace. If your laptop is designed for SATA 2 or 2.6, a drive for SATA 3 will not work in any case.

Samsung EVO claims to be compatible with SATA 2 or 2.6. I have verified it on a single laptop here. Perhaps this compatibility is not given in any case. Please verify this.

Comment: I found the reference of the old HDD. https://www.inmac-wstore.com/wd-blue-wd10spzx-disque-dur-1-to-sata-6gb-s/p7121645.htm // it says that it has a sata-600 interface which correspond to 600mb/s. This rate is the one of SATA III

Comment: Also my computer is 3 years old, that would be weird to use SATA II.

Comment: i.imgur.com/TASKPQo.png so it's SATA 6

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Since BIOS update 1.04, the system doesn't allow to add an SSD with more than 512GB through SATA interface.
https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/674891/#Comment_674891

Since M.2 also use SATA, those are also concerned by this, you'll need a PCIE interface (nVME drives) to bypass this limitation

From here you have 2 solutions if you don't have any PCIe interface:

- buy an SSD with less than 512GB
- downgrade your BIOS to v1.03 (with all the risks involved)